# Upgrade from Spring Boot 1.3 to Spring Boot 1.4 and Pageable is not working as expected.

Tags: spring-boot

I am converting an existing Spring Boot application from 1.3.6 to 1.4.1. I would like to have a default page size for repository and controller responses of 25.  I am not getting the expected behavior in either case. For repository methods I am getting a page size of 20.  For controllers I am getting 0 for the page size.

I added a new configuration class to define the default page size.  I found this code snippet in another article.  The debug message does get printed out.

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfigurationAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final int DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 25;

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        System.out.println("DEBUG: AddArguments----");
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        resolver.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(0, DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE));
        argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    }


}
```

In a custom controller I would like to have a default pageable populated with a size of 25.  However the pageable object is null in this controller.  In 1.3.x the pageable object worked as expected.

```
public class BatchManagerController
{
    @Autowired
    private BatchRepository batchRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PagedResourcesAssembler pagedResourcesAssembler;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search/managerBatchView", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole(T(com.nextgearcapital.tms.api.util.AuthorityEnum).MANAGER)")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getManagerBatchListView(BatchListSearchRequest requestDTO, Pageable pageable, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler myAssembler)
    {
        System.out.println("DEBUG1:---------- " + pageable);
        Page<Batch> batchPage = batchRepository.findBatchesForManager(requestDTO, pageable);
        PagedResources<VaultResource> pagedResources = pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(batchPage, myAssembler);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(pagedResources, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

When calling SDR Repository methods with a pageable parameter, the parameter works correctly, but it has a default page size of 20, rather than 25.

I would appreciate any help and advise in getting the correct configuration for pagination.

Comment: Make your `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` a `@Bean` that will prevent the autoconfiguration to override/register another one. Or, maybe even better, is to create a `BeanPostProcessor` which will operate on the already existing `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and do some additional configuration on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have 2 solutions

1. Register the `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` as an `@Bean` which will disable the auto configuration for Spring Data Web.
2. Create a `BeanPostProcessor` to do additional configuration on the existing `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

#### Using `@Bean`

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfigurationAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final int DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 25;

    @Bean
    public PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver() {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        resolver.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(0, DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE));
        return resolver;
   }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        System.out.println("DEBUG: AddArguments----");
        argumentResolvers.add(pageableResolver());
    }
}
```

Drawback is that it will disable the autoconfiguration for Spring Data Web, so you might miss some things.

#### Using a `BeanPostProcessor`.

```
@Bean
public BeanPostProcessor pageableProcessor() {

    private static final int DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 25;

    return new BeanPostProcessor() {
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver) {
                ((PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver) bean).setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(0, DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE));
            }
            return bean;
        }

        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
        }
    }
}
```

Drawback is that it is a little more complex as registering your own `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` instance as a bean. Advantage however is that you can simply use this to add additional configuration to existing beans and leave the auto configuration in tact.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Both of these solutions worked for the SDR repository methods.  However, neither of them worked, for me, for accepting a Pageable object in a custom controller method.  In a custom controller method the pageable parameter is always null in SB 1.4.  I can read in the parameters,size, page and build a PageRequest object in the custom method.  But, I didn't have to do that in 1.3.x.  I appreciate your response it was a big help.

Comment: That is odd as it still should give you the defaults. Which makes me wonder if somehow you end up with multiple `RequestMethodHandlerAdapters` or something like that (as it certainly looks like that). You don't manually configure your web stuff do you?

Comment: I don't believe I have any manually configured web stuff.  I did just discover that if I change the parameter from "Pageable pageable" to "DefaultedPageable pageable", and then use "pageable.getPageable()" I am getting the pageable object that contains the pageable information from the request.  I don't know if that is an appropriate way to proceed or not.  I am going to research whether I should use the DefaultedPageable object as a custom controller parameter rather than Pageable.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using the `Pageable` should be all you need. It just looks like the method parameter resolution doesn't kick in here, and I don't know why. Just for testing could you try without `@Transactional` and `@PreAuthorize` see if that helps.

Comment: Could it be that you are running into [DATAREST-906](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-906)? It certainly looks like it. You could try to update the Spring Data release train to the latest nightly and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you!  I was hitting the DATAREST-906 bug. When I pulled in spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT the pageable parameter in my RepositoryRestControllers work as expected.  I appreciate the tip, it was a very big help.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in `spring-data-commons` version `2.0`, there is are 2 new classes that *might* make this kind of thing easier:

- `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer`
- `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer`

Unfortunately that's not the version that ships with the current version (1.5.9) of Spring Boot, so replace at your own risk.

```
@Bean 
PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer pagingCustomizer() {
    // p is PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver
    return p -> p.setMaxPageSize(25);
}
```

In this case, one would probably call `resolveArgument` to manipulate it.

That said, I'm not sure `spring-data-rest` would use that config. There is a `HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` which seems more likely that source of what I would think SDR would use. If that's the case, the `BeanPostProcessor` @M. Deinum suggested is probably your best option.

[Spring Data Web Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web)